# Is it possible to invoke OS X services programmatically?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to create new task in Appigo Todo for Mac from Alfred here. Since it provide OS X service in the service menu to let me highlight any text and create a new task from that. Is it possible to send a text to this service programmatically? (Shell script, AppleScripts, Automator, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to handle this.

Here's an example of a shell command that will send a keystroke to the frontmost app via applescript:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"a\""
```

Also have a look at [Cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/), [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) (from MacPorts) and [pymaCursor](https://github.com/pudquick/pymaCursor).

You might also want to consider a UI automator like [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/)

Comment: Is it really impossible to call services directly? This method seem... inelegant. It's not as fast since we need to wait for UI to update along the way and prone to error as well.

Comment: But what is "directly"?  A shell script has its internal structure for handling execution flow and variables, but anything that it runs is an external program.  Shell doesn't have any of its own hooks to the GUI. AppleScript does, so if you want to write something purely in AppleScript, that might be an option ... But to schedule it, your crontab is still launching things from shell.  If you prefer to work in a GUI, you may want to look at tools like [cronnix](http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/).

Answer (score 0):

[**Invoking a Service Programmatically**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000854-97922-CEGEIEDA)

Though the user typically invokes a standard service by choosing an item in the Services menu, you can invoke it in code using this function:

```
BOOL NSPerformService(NSString *serviceItem, NSPasteboard *pboard)
```

This function returns `YES` if the service is successfully performed; otherwise, it returns `NO`. The name of a Services menu item (in any language) is contained in serviceItem. It must be the full name of the service; for example, `“Search in Google.”` The parameter pboard contains the data to be used for the service, and, when the function returns, it contains the data returned from the service. You can then do with the data what you wish.